# Twiml discarding voice, loop in SAY verb inside GATHER

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have an API which first creates a call to a number using the C# wrapper, lets say the receiver is +1000000001

```cs
var call = CallResource.Create(new PhoneNumber("+1000000001"),
                        new PhoneNumber("MYVERIFIEDNUMBER"),
                        url: new Uri("https://api.com/answered"),
                        method: HttpMethod.Get,
                        client: _client,
                        sendDigits: ""
                        );
```

When answered the TWIML returned from https://api.com/answered is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="https://api.com/connect/6AE3045C0D024F1896BF7ECFCB2FC40A" method="GET">
    <Say voice="alice" loop="0" language="en">Press any key to connect to John Doe, , </Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

This should result in an infinite loop in the voice of "alice" for the SAY verb being repeated to the receiver at +1000000001 but it is a male robotic voice and it only repeats once then drops the call.  This is first part of the issue.

The second part is the GATHER verb does nothing.  I should be able to press a touch tone phone and have the url https://api.com/connect/6AE3045C0D024F1896BF7ECFCB2FC40A return

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>client:6AE3045C0D024F1896BF7ECFCB2FC40A</Dial>
  <Hangup></Hangup>
</Response>
```

which it does on the GET request but I can never get to it because of the GATHER issue

The third part is does this look correct to dial a client app?

```xml
<Dial>client:6AE3045C0D024F1896BF7ECFCB2FC40A</Dial>
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You have `loop="0"` which makes it only play once. Also `language="en"` isn't a valid language option. I presume you want `language="en-US"`

Comment: Somebody correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're wrong on both counts. twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say#attributes-loop seems to suggest that loop="0" will cause an infinite loop until hung up. I also tried this 6 months ago and it looped infinitely, well within reason - I think it lasted around 20 minutes. Any more required further SAY verbs. twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say#attributes-language suggests 'The default is English with an American accent (en)' & also 'select English with an American accent (en)'

Comment: Looks like you're correct on the loop. But for the language, as the doc says, "en" is for "man" or "woman". The default for Alice is en-US so you can leave the language attribute off if that's the one you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Alice defaults to en-US so you can leave the language attribute off. Also, can you make sure you are returning TwiML with the right MIME type, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilio-understands-mime-types.

Client is used inorrectly, refer to the TwiML syntax here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/twiml.

Let me know if that addresses the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the docs on CLIENT, I've adjusted the code. I'll look at the MIME type now

Comment: The MIME type was incorrectly set to text/plain, once set to text/xml everything worked as expected.  I can't up-vote you because of <15 reputation but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.